# Multiple UI threads in Cocoa

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, user-interface, nsview

I have a Mac OS X server application that renders NSViews and returns them over an HTTP interface as images for use elsewhere. There's no visible UI, and the application creates detached NSViews without an NSWindow.

The application can receive many requests at once, but the layout and rendering process is synchronized around the main thread (using dispatch_sync in GCD) as Cocoa UI isn't thread safe, reducing the throughput to a single request at a time in that portion of the code.

Given that each request is entirely separate, with nothing shared between them, is there a way for a Cocoa application to effectively run multiple, entirely separate UI threads? Perhaps using multiple run loops?

I'd like to avoid having to run multiple processes, if possible.

Comment: I think we'll need some more details here. You say it renders NSViews. How is it doing this? (i.e. are you manually calling `-drawRect:`?) What's in the views?

Comment: Since Snow Leopard, there is support, in the normal flow of things (i.e. NSViews that are actually participating in a presented UI) for concurrent drawing on background threads (see `-[NSView canDrawConcurrently]`) But it doesn't sound like that's what you're doing (since the views are never associated with the view hierarchy of a window.) But again... we need more details.

Comment: yes.. drawing can happen concurrently but much of the API isn't 'thread safe' at all

Comment: Since the goal he's trying to achieve is 'rendering NSViews' concurrent drawing seems quite relevant.

Comment: I'm creating an array of NSViews (one per page) and associated subviews (NSImageViews + text laid out using Core Text Layout System) and then calling `[view displayRectIgnoringOpacity:view.bounds inContext:graphicsContext]` where the context is an NSGraphicsContext for an NSBitmapImageRep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say with certainty that this will work for your specific needs (since your specific needs may have main-thread dependencies not called out in your question) but I don't see anything particularly controversial here. For instance, the following code works just fine without incident:

```
CGImageRef CreateImageFromView(NSView* view)
{
    const CGSize contextSize = CGSizeMake(ceil(view.frame.size.width), ceil(view.frame.size.height));
    const size_t width = contextSize.width;
    const size_t height = contextSize.height;
    const size_t bytesPerPixel = 32;
    const size_t bitmapBytesPerRow = 64 * ((width * bytesPerPixel + 63) / 64 ); // Alignment
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    [view displayRectIgnoringOpacity: view.bounds inContext: [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort: context flipped: YES]];
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return image;
}

- (IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender
{
    static NSUInteger count = 0;

    for (NSUInteger i =0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSButton* button = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100)] autorelease];
            button.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Done Stuff %lu Times", (unsigned long)count++];
            CGImageRef image = CreateImageFromView(button);
            NSImage* nsImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image size: NSMakeSize(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image))] autorelease];
            CGImageRelease(image);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageView.image = nsImage;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The key here is that everything be "private" to the background rendering task. It gets its own view, its own graphics context, etc. If you aren't sharing anything, this should be OK. Since you explicitly said, "Given that each request is entirely separate, with nothing shared between them", I suspect you've already satisfied this condition.

Try it out. Leave a comment if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks ipmcc, this set me on the right path. When I was testing before, I was accidentally attempting to rasterize multiple pages in the same document simultaneously, which was causing problems with the common Core Text objects. I'm putting each page through a per-document serial dispatch queue now, and it's able to process multiple documents simultaneously, without stepping on each other. Another, possibly related bug, was that I was unnecessarily saving and restoring shared NSGraphicsContext stack. I'm now creating an independent NSGraphicsContext, so the main stack is unaffected.

Comment: Assuming the documents are immutable, you can probably also parallelize operations within the same document by making private copies of the CoreText objects as well.

Comment: @ipmcc I tried executing your code, but the app crashed saying:
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[NSButton initWithFrame:] -[NSButton initWithFrame:] must be used from main thread only. Can you explain how can we use dispatch_async to extract a View from a NSButton (in your case) or View from ViewController in my case as we know the Main thread is required for UI api's to work?
I am creating a PDF generation OSX app where I need to create View from different ViewControllers and then convert view to NSImage to generate PDF page.